# Aggregating Two Django Models with No Direct Relationship - Translating Pandas to Django ORM

Tags: django, pandas, django-orm, aggregation

I am currently aggregating two QuerySets by merging them based off of a key "pl_id" and grouping by two additional attributes, "zip_code" and "num_itms" with Pandas, but in production this is far too slow due to the large size of the datasets.  I have tried multiple approaches with SubQueries but nothing is working, as the subqueries return multiple values.  Zip codes is an ArrayField and is being unnested with the Postgres function, this seems to be complicating my goal.  Is there a way to achieve this Pandas aggregation with Django ORM?

```
result = (
    pd.DataFrame.from_records(
        self.offer_query.annotate(
            partner_id=F("l__p_id"),
            zip_code=Func(
                F("l__ra__zip_codes_array"),
                function="unnest",
            ),
        ).values("zip_code", "p_id", "pl_id")
    )
    .merge(
        pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            self.prices_query.values(
                "pl_id",
                "num_items",
                "price",
            )
        ),
        on="pl_id",
    )
    .groupby(["zip_code", "num_items"])
    .agg(
        count=("p_id", "count"),
        min=("price", "min"),
        max=("price", "max"),
    )
    .reset_index()
)
```

I have already tried a subquery for each aggregation.